# How to update existing record using codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table like this: `id`, `image`, `user_id`.

The `user_id` is saved from the session. The same user wants to update his profile picture means, how it will update?

**This Is Controller Function**

```
public function save() {

   $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
   $uid= $session_data['id'];

   //print_r($uid);exit;

   $url = $this->do_upload();
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $this->user_model->save($url,$uid);

   echo '<script>alert("You Have Successfully Uploaded your Profile Picture!");</script>';

   redirect('/home/');
}
```

**This Is Model**

```
public function save($url, $uid){
    $this->db->set('image', $url);
    $this->db->set('user_id', $uid);
    $this->db->insert('tbl');
    return true;
}
```

How can I update this query?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following:

```
$upd_data = array(
   'image' = $url,
);

$this->db->where('user_id', $uid)
         ->update('tbl', $upd_data);
```

Comment: //model  public function update_image($url,$uid){

  $data=array('image'=>$url,'user_id'=>$uid);
  $this->db->where('user_id',$uid);
  $this->db->update('tbl',$data);
  return true;
 }

Comment: controller//public function update_image(){
   

   $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
   $uid= $session_data['id'];



   //print_r($uid);exit;
   $this->load->view('main_update');
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $url = $this->do_upload();
   
   $this->user_model->update_image($url,$uid);}

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your comments as they are not readable at this moment.

Comment: hi,are you understand what i did?