# How to update 3 table existing data by id in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have data that already exists in the database server and I want to change it based on the id table. I want to update one time so that the 3 data tables are updated as well because the table id is in another table too. I tried it but I can't. Please help me

I have joined from several tables.
I've also searched on :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356776/how-to-update-form-data-in-codeigniter)! 
:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253589/how-to-update-existing-record-using-codeigniter)!

This is my **Controller**

```
public function updateservicenew(){
$id= $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['vendor']= $this->model_vendor->show_data_all();
$data['vendor2']= $this->model_vendor->show_data_vendor2();
$data['service']= $this->Madmin2->getservicenew($id)->row_array();
$this->template->viewadmin2('admin2/transaks/updateservicenew',$data);
}
public function saveservicenew(){
$this->Madmin2->saveservicenew($this->input->post());
redirect(base_url('admin2/transaksidone'));
}
```

This is my **Model**

```
public function getservicenew($id){     $this->db->select('kontak_sis.*,vendor.*,vendor2.*,service_sis.*,sumber_info.*,provinsi.*,kota.*,mst_service.*,service.*');
$this->db->from('service_sis');
$this->db->join('vendor', 'service_sis.id_vendor=vendor.id_vendor', 'left');
$this->db->join('vendor2', 'service_sis.id_vendor2=vendor2.id_vendor2', 'left');
$this->db->join('mst_service', 'service_sis.id_mst_service=mst_service.id_mst_service', 'left');
$this->db->join('kontak_sis', 'service_sis.id_kontak=kontak_sis.id_kontak', 'left');
$this->db->join('sumber_info', 'service_sis.id_sumber=sumber_info.id_sumber', 'left');
$this->db->join('provinsi', 'service_sis.id_provinsi=provinsi.id_provinsi', 'left');
$this->db->join('kota', 'service_sis.id_kota=kota.id_kota', 'left');
$this->db->join('service', 'service_sis.id_service=service.id_service', 'left');
$param = array('service_sis.id_service'=>$id);
return $this->db->get_where('',$param);
}
public function simpanservicenew(){
$data_pelanggan['cid']= $this->input->post('cid');
$data_pelanggan['nama_perusahaan']= $this->input->post('nama_perusahaan');
$data_pelanggan['destination']= $this->input->post('destination');
$data_pelanggan['alamat_perusahaan']= $this->input->post('alamat_perusahaan');
$data_pelanggan['pic_perusahaan']= $this->input->post('pic_perusahaan');
$data_pelanggan['telepon_pic']= $this->input->post('telepon_pic');
$data_pelanggan['fax']= $this->input->post('fax');
$data_pelanggan['hp']= $this->input->post('hp');
$data_pelanggan['email_pic']= $this->input->post('email_pic');

$this->db->where('id_kontak',$this->input->post('id_kontak'));
$this->db->update('kontak_sis',$data_pelanggan);

$data_vendor['pic_vendor']= $this->input->post('pic_vendor');
$data_vendor['media_vendor']= $this->input->post('media_vendor');
$data_vendor['kapasitas_vendor']= $this->input->post('kapasitas_vendor');
$data_vendor['telepon_vendor']= $this->input->post('telepon_vendor');
$data_vendor['email_vendor']= $this->input->post('email_vendor');

$this->db->where('id_vendor',$this->input->post('id_vendor'));
$this->db->update('vendor',$data_vendor);

$data_vendor2['pic_vendor2']= $this->input->post('pic_vendor2');
$data_vendor2['media_vendor2']= $this->input->post('media_vendor2');
$data_vendor2['kapasitas_vendor2']= $this->input->post('kapasitas_vendor2');
$data_vendor2['telepon_vendor2']= $this->input->post('telepon_vendor2');
$data_vendor2['email_vendor2']= $this->input->post('email_vendor2');

$this->db->where('id_vendor2',$this->input->post('id_vendor2'));
$this->db->update('vendor2',$data_vendor2);
```

This is my **View**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
    <div id='progress'><div id='progress-complete'></div></div>
    <h2 class="box-title"><b>Set Ewo</b></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('admin2/simpanservicebaru/'.$this->uri->segment(3)); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_service" value="<?php echo $service['id_service']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_kontak" value="<?php echo $service['id_kontak']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_mst_service" value="<?php echo $service['id_mst_service']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_vendor" value="<?php echo $service['id_vendor']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_vendor2" value="<?php echo $service['id_vendor2']; ?>">

    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Registration Form ID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cid" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $service['cid'] ?>" readonly>
                        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Customer</label>
                            <b><input type="text" name="nama_perusahaan" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $service['nama_perusahaan']; ?>"required></b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Destination</label>
                            <b><input type="text" name="destination" class="form-control" placeholder="destination" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['destination']; ?>"required></b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Address</label>
                            <b><input type="text" name="alamat_perusahaan" class="form-control" placeholder="alamat" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['alamat_perusahaan']; ?>"required></b>
                        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">PIC(Engineering)</label>
                            <input type="text" name="pic_perusahaan" class="form-control" placeholder="pic"
                            value="<?php echo $service['pic_perusahaan']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telepon_pic" class="form-control" placeholder="phone number" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['telepon_pic']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Fax</label>
                            <input type="text" name="fax" class="form-control" placeholder="fax" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['fax']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">HP</label>
                            <input type="text" name="hp" class="form-control" placeholder="hp"
                            value="<?php echo $service['hp']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email_pic" class="form-control" placeholder="email pic" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['email_pic']; ?>">
                        </div>
    </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Vendor1</label>
                            <select name="id_vendor" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Non Vendor</option>

                        <?php
                        foreach ($vendor as $c)
                        { ?>
                          <?php $sel = ($c->id_vendor==$service['id_vendor']) ? 'selected' :''; ?>
                                 <option value="<?php echo $c->id_vendor;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo $c->nama_vendor;?></option>
                        <?php }   ?>

                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">PIC</label>
                            <input type="text" name="pic_vendor" class="form-control" placeholder="pic vendor" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['pic_vendor']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Media</label>
                            <input type="text" name="media_vendor" class="form-control" placeholder="media" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['media_vendor']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Capacity</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kapasitas_vendor" class="form-control" placeholder="kapasitas vendor" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['kapasitas_vendor']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telepon_vendor" class="form-control" placeholder="telepon vendor" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['telepon_vendor']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email_vendor" class="form-control" placeholder="email vendor" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['email_vendor']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <hr></hr>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Vendor2</label>
                            <select name="id_vendor2" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Non Vendor</option>

                        <?php
                        foreach ($vendor2 as $c)
                        { ?>
                          <?php $sel = ($c->id_vendor2==$service['id_vendor2']) ? 'selected' :''; ?>
                                 <option value="<?php echo $c->id_vendor2;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo $c->nama_vendor2;?></option>
                        <?php }   ?>

                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">PIC</label>
                            <input type="text" name="pic_vendor2" class="form-control" placeholder="pic vendor" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['pic_vendor2']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Media</label>
                            <input type="text" name="media_vendor2" class="form-control" placeholder="media" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['media_vendor2']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Capacity</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kapasitas_vendor2" class="form-control" placeholder="kapasitas vendor" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['kapasitas_vendor2']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telepon_vendor2" class="form-control" placeholder="telepon vendor"
                            value="<?php echo $service['telepon_vendor2']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email_vendor2" class="form-control" placeholder="email vendor" 
                            value="<?php echo $service['email_vendor2']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                        <br>
                            <p>*Pastikan semua form sudah terisi dengan benar</p>
                        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update Service</button>
                        </fieldset>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
       $( function() {
          var $signupForm = $( '#myForm' );
          $signupForm.validate({errorElement: 'em'});
          $signupForm.formToWizard({
          submitButton: 'submit',
          nextBtnName:  'Selanjutnya',
          prevBtnName:  'Sebelumnya',
          nextBtnClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-flat next',
          prevBtnClass: 'btn btn-default btn-flat prev',
          buttonTag:    'button',
          validateBeforeNext: function(form, step) {
              var stepIsValid = true;
              var validator = form.validate();
              $(':input', step).each( function(index) {
                  var xy = validator.element(this);
                  stepIsValid = stepIsValid && (typeof xy == 'undefined' || xy);
              });
              return stepIsValid;
          },
          progress: function (i, count) {
              $('#progress-complete').width(''+(i/count*100)+'%');
          }

          });
       });
    </script>
```

Tables:

```
This is my **Table contact**
#  Name   type
1   id_kontak int(11)
2   cid    varchar(10)
3   nama_perusahaan    varchar(150)
4   destination    varchar(30)
5   alamat_perusahaan   varchar(200)
6   pic_perusahaan   varchar(200)
7   telepon_pic   varchar(30)
8   fax  int(15)
9   hp  int(15)
10  email_pic  (15)

This my **table vendor**
#  Name   type
1   id_vendor int(11)
2   pic_vendor     varchar(200)
3   telepon_vendor    varchar(100)
4   media_vendor    varchar(200)
5   kapasitas_vendor  varchar(200)
6   email_vendor   varchar(200)

This my **table vendor2**
#  Name   type
1   id_vendor2 int(11)
2   pic_vendor2     varchar(200)
3   telepon_vendor2    varchar(100)
4   media_vendor2    varchar(200)
5   kapasitas_vendor2  varchar(200)
6   email_vendor2   varchar(200)
```

I want to update one time so that the 3 data tables are updated as well because the table id is in another table too.Thank you for the help

Comment: Show your tables structure.

Comment: In order for us to help you, you need to describe what exactly is happening. *something* must be happening, database error? blank page? first thing you need to do is to allow yourself time to see what is happening. debugging 101: remove this `redirect(base_url('admin2/transaksidone'));` and turn on `db_debug` in `database.php`

Comment: how to display it?

Comment: display what? if you mean errors, add it as an image to your post via the edit button.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The thing is, you have given us a big bucket of code, but you haven't explained three things: 1) what happens with your code, 2) what you want to have happen instead, and 3) what you've tried to fix it. In your case you talk about database tables, but you don't show them. Maybe someone here could read your code and figure it out (wow! that's a lot of joins!) but if I understand your question, all that code doesn't matter much. It sounds like you want to ask, "with this data in table A, how to I update tables B and C?" To answer that question, we have to see the tables

Comment: I have added the structur table to the view. Please check again

Comment: you have said what error you are getting after following my previous instructions. this is important because i think that is where you error lies.

Comment: I have tried to follow @ alex's suggestion, there is no error notification but the data is not updated to the database

Comment: the problem is I have updated the data in CI but the data is not updated to the database and there is no show error message

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your code is that you want to update 3 tables using single query. In that case you can use following code.

```
$this->db->set('a.cid', $this->input->post('cid'));
$this->db->set('a.nama_perusahaan',  $this->input->post('nama_perusahaan'));

$this->db->set('b.pic_vendor', $this->input->post('pic_vendor'));
$this->db->set('b.media_vendor', $this->input->post('media_vendor'));

$this->db->set('c.pic_vendor2', $this->input->post('pic_vendor2'));
$this->db->set('c.companyaddress', $this->input->post('pic_vendor2'));

$this->db->where('a.id', 1);
$this->db->where('a.id = b.id');
$this->db->where('a.id = c.id');
$this->db->update('table as a, table2 as b',table3 as c);
```

But in na More Professional way you should use [Codeigniter Transactions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html). If any of the query fails the other one gets rolled back.

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
    $this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
    $this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
    $this->db->trans_complete();
```